# React Axios POST request getting stalled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to login using Axios POST request.

Somehow, the request got stalled and I'm not sure what to do as this is the first time I'm learning this stack.

If there's any common thing that cause this, it would be a great help for me.

**DemoLogin.js**

```
handleLoginFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    axios
      .post("/users/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          message: "success",
          isLoggedIn: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          username: "",
          password: "",
          message: `${err.response.data}`
        });
      });
  }
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you make sure the call ever reached your server?

Comment: How can I do that? @PrashantVishwakarma

Comment: Check for logs in your login service?

Comment: The call only reached after I refresh the page, and it only states the logs like this "POST /users/login - - ms - - @PrashantVishwakarma